# HJM model - Differentiation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, finance

starting from the folowing SDE (HJM model):

$$df(t,T)=\left(\sigma(t,T)'\int_t^T{\sigma(t,u)du}\right)dt+\sigma(t,T)'dW_t$$

And having $r(t)=f(t,t)$, I have two questions :

1) how do we obtain the folowing differential equation :

$$dr(t)=df(t,T)|_{T=t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial T}f(t,T)|_{T=t}dt$$

I also think that i don't know how to read the derlimiter $\vert$. For me it does make sense doing this (replacing $T$ by $t$ in $df(t,T)|_{T=t}$):

$$dr(t)=df(t,t)=df(t,T)|_{T=t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial T}f(t,T)|_{T=t}dt =df(t,t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial T}f(t,T)|_{T=t}dt$$

which means $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}f(t,T)|_{T=t}dt=0$ ?

2) In the case $\sigma$ is constant scalar, how do we find the folowing? :

$$dr(t)=\sigma dW_t+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}f(0,T)|_{T=t}+\sigma^2t\right)dt$$

NB: this is from my reading of Paul Glasserman, Monte Carlo Methods In Financial Engineering, page 153

thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you should not mix $df(t, T)|_{T=t}$ with $df(t, t)$. For  $df(t, T)|_{T=t}$, there is no differential to the second argument, that is,  when taking the differential, the second argument is ignored, while setting $T$ to $t$ after the differential is done. However,  for $df(t, t)$, you need to consider the differential for both the first and second arguments.

For your second question, if $\sigma$ is a constant, then
\begin{align*}
df(t, T) = \sigma^2(T-t)dt + \sigma dW_t.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) &= f(0, T) + \int_0^t \sigma^2(T-s)ds +\sigma W_t\\
&=f(0, T)+ \sigma^2 Tt -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2 +\sigma W_t.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
r_t = f(0, t) +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2 +\sigma W_t.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
dr_t &= \frac{\partial f(0, T)}{\partial T}\big|_{T=t} dt +\sigma^2 t\, dt + \sigma \,dW_t\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial f(0, T)}{\partial T}\big|_{T=t} + \sigma^2 t \right)dt + \sigma \,dW_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: again thank you @Gordon. that's accurate and clear. very helpful! Could you advice me any book/tutorial so i can get used to this type of concepts? thank you in advance

Comment: @Daveddd: I do not know your background, but can start with the book by Brigo on interest rate models: http://www.amazon.com/Interest-Rate-Models-Damiano-Brigo/dp/3540417729.

Comment: thank you. i already read Part 1 of Brigo. i find some parts a little difficult but managed to do the proofs. I don't have a strong mathematical backgroud, so spending some time to read that kind book.

Comment: @Daveddd: Brigo's book is pretty readable. Taking some time, you should be able to manage it.

Comment: I'll work on Brigo's book. Your answers to my questions are of a great help!! thank you